# Out of memory during second pass of loss.backward() (torch.nn.NLLLoss())

Tags: pytorch

I'm doing some basic experimentation with pytorch, and I've run into an issue I can't seem to resolve: during the second batch the system runs out of its 64GB memory and kills the process when it is executing loss.backward(). I've tried deleting the loss function between batches, and reduced the batch size to something really small. This example has a lot of classes, so it is reasonable that it uses a lot of memory. However, I don't understand what I'm doing that increases memory usage during the second pass?

```
    print("Creating W", flush=True)
    emb = nn.Embedding(len(xInx), len(vocabX))
    W = torch.rand([len(vocabX), len(vocabY)], requires_grad=True)
    print(
        "Created W, getsizeof:",
        sys.getsizeof(W),
        "torch size:",
        W.element_size() * W.nelement(),
        flush=True,
    )

    smaxFunc = torch.nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
    lossFunc = torch.nn.NLLLoss()
    epochs = 2
    minImprovement = 0.001
    oldLoss = 10 ^ 5
    baseLr = 100
    batchSize = 100

    print("Starting training, training examples:", len(xInx), flush=True)
    for cnt in range(1, epochs):
        b = 1
        for xInxBatch, yInxBatch in zip(
            makeBatches(xInx, batchSize), makeBatches(yInx, batchSize)
        ):
            print("1", flush=True)
            xOneHot = emb(xInxBatch)
            
            print("2", flush=True)
            S = xOneHot @ W

            print("3", flush=True)
            yhat = smaxFunc(S)

            print("4", flush=True)
            loss = lossFunc(yhat, yInxBatch)

            print("5", flush=True)
            W.grad = None

            print("6", flush=True)
            loss.backward()

            print(cnt, b, "loss", loss.item())
            b += 1

            print("7", flush=True)
            W.data += -baseLr / cnt * W.grad

            print("8", flush=True)
            if abs(loss.item() - oldLoss) < minImprovement:
                print(f"Training stagnated at {cnt} epochs")
                break
            oldLoss = int(loss.item())
            del loss
```

Here is the output from this snippet:

```
Creating W
Created W, getsizeof: 88 torch size: 2207412
Starting training, training examples: 314049
1
2
3
4
5
6
1 1 loss 75.59652709960938
7
8
1
2
3
4
5
6
Killed
```